# Listing Cascade Update / Delete Referential Integrity Rules in an MS-Access Database?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003, referential-integrity

In MS-Access I'm aware of referential integrity rules such as cascading updates and deletes and creating them using DDL.

But after the tables have already been created, how can these be listed again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA you can use TableDefs and Relations collections to show table and relationship properties. You can also use ADO Schemas to get information.

In particular, you will wish to refer to the attributes of the relationship:

```
Name                    Value       Description
dbRelationDeleteCascade 4096        Deletions cascade
dbRelationDontEnforce   2           Relationship not enforced (no referential integrity)
dbRelationInherited     4           Relationship exists in the database containing the two linked tables
dbRelationLeft          16777216    Microsoft Access only. In Design view, display a LEFT JOIN as the default join type.
dbRelationRight         33554432    Microsoft Access only. In Design view, display a RIGHT JOIN as the default join type.
dbRelationUnique        1           One-to-one relationship
dbRelationUpdateCascade 256         Updates cascade
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225809.aspx

```
Dim rel As Relation
Dim tdf As TableDef

For Each rel In CurrentDb.Relations
    Debug.Print rel.Attributes
Next
```

4352 = dbRelationUpdateCascade + dbRelationDeleteCascade